# Allowing pop-ups from specific URLs in Edge, using Intune

Tags: internet-explorer, popup, microsoft-edge, mdm, intune

I need to allow pop-ups in Edge from a specific URL.  (Win 10 1803.)

I have found the Browser/AllowPopups Policy CSP: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/policy-csp-browser#browser-allowpopups

While I could create a profile and enter it in the Custom OMA-URI Settings:

[image: Custom OMA-URI Settings]

it seems to be binary - either pop-ups are on or off:

Supported values:

- Blank - Users can choose to use Pop-up Blocker.
- 0 (default) – Turn
  off Pop-up Blocker letting pop-up windows open.
- 1 – Turn on Pop-up
  Blocker stopping pop-up windows from opening.

How do I allow pop-ups from only a defined list of URLs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At present, it's not possible to turn pop ups on/off for specific websites, we can either block all the pop-ups or allow it. I have feedback this issue with Microsoft, hope they can solve this issue.